# Yeoman SharePoint Framework webpart generator error

Tags: sharepoint, yeoman, yeoman-generator, spfx

I'm new to Yeoman so any help would really be useful.

When attempting to use the Yeoman SharePoint Framework webpart generator I get the following error:

```
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: Cannot find "package.json" file required by this generator
    at WebpartGenerator.get [as packageJson] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@microsoft/generator-sharepoint/lib/common/BaseGenerator.js:45:23)
    at WebpartGenerator.BaseGenerator.ensureDependencyGroup (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@microsoft/generator-sharepoint/lib/common/BaseGenerator.js:96:18)
    at WebpartGenerator.BaseComponentGenerator.configuring (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@microsoft/generator-sharepoint/lib/generators/component/BaseComponentGenerator.js:95:14)
    at WebpartGenerator.configuring (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@microsoft/generator-sharepoint/lib/generators/webpart/index.js:43:38)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@microsoft/generator-sharepoint/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/index.js:408:23)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@microsoft/generator-sharepoint/node_modules/run-async/index.js:25:25
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@microsoft/generator-sharepoint/node_modules/run-async/index.js:24:19
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@microsoft/generator-sharepoint/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/index.js:409:9
    at runCallback (timers.js:672:20)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:645:5)
```

Comment: it seems this might be the cause but i'm not sure how to solve it, get this message just after i run  `yo @microsoft/sharepoint` i get `Just found a ``.yo-rc.json`` in a parent directory.`
`Setting the project root at: /Users/admin/spfx'`

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things that you need to check:

1) Ensure that you are using the Node.js LTS version.
If unsure, uninstall the Node js, and download it from here - [Node v6.11](https://nodejs.org/dist/v6.11.2/node-v6.11.2-x64.msi)

2) Ensure that your NPM version is 3.x. SPFx is currently not compatible with NPM 5.

You can check that by running the `npm -v` command in the command line.

If its version 5, you can downgrade it by running the below command:

```
npm install -g npm3
```

3) Once done, you can install the latest yeoman template of spfx as below:

```
npm install @microsoft/generator-sharepoint@latest -g
```

4) After that, you can run the `yo @microsoft/sharepoint` command to create SPFx webpart

Comment: Thanks for this, before i try the steps, does it affect anything that it has worked previously?

Comment: No it doesn't affect.

Comment: Should i of mentioned i'm on Mac OSX? i notice the version you've included is for windows.

Comment: ahh ok, that explains, you can download it from here [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)

Comment: So i've tried the steps above to no change unfortunately. What i have done is to create the SPFx webpart in a new directory, which works fine, but then `gulp serve` does not work. Thanks for all your help on this

Comment: No idea why that happens on Mac Os, but you can run `gulp serve --nobrowser` and then open the workbench page on sharepoint whose url would be `https://tenantname.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/workbench.aspx` and you would be able to add /test the webpart

Answer (score 0):

This is reproduced in the following way.

1. Generate SPFx Project in Parent folder.
2. Make sub folder (ex. Sub1) and move all the visible files to that folder using Finder.
   (Note. All the hidden files that starts with . are left in the parent folder with this step)
3. Make another folder (ex. Sub2) and generate SPFx project again. And here this error is shown.

In step 2, it was necessary to move all the hidden files to the child folder.
Anyway, workaround of this issue is to use unrelated brand new folder such as Parent2.

Parent (Sub1, Sub2), Parent2